# How is the output of the below program 556?

Tags: c, pointers

Below is the code

```
int main()
{
    int a=300;
    char *b = (char *)&a;
    *++b=2;
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints 556

Please explain!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you think *should* be happening and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: On a little endian machine, this is ( 300 - 256 ) + ( 256 * 2 ). Try it on a calculator.

Comment: On a big endian machine (if you can find one) it will be completely different.

Comment: @AdrianMole *b is assigned with ','(128+128+44=300) 44 being the ASCII value of ','.
++b increments to the next address and 2(ASCII is STX ) is stored in that address. I don't understand what's happening next and I might be wrong with the above explanation

Comment: I'm sorry, but the "explanation" in your comment doesn't really explain what you are trying to achive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you are new to programming or C in general.  If you think of char as a byte, it is easier to follow.  A calculator that does binary will help too.

```
    int a=300;
    char *b = (char *)&a;
```

Take integer (`a`) and point to its address as a `char*` (think of this as a byte pointer).  In binary, here are your variables:

```
 a: 0000 0001 0010 1100 (300)
*b:           0010 1100 (44)
```

Because it's type `char*`, it only points to the first byte.

```
*++b=2; /* Same as *(++b) = 2; */
```

First, we advance `b` by one byte. `*b` now points at the second byte of `a`:

```
 a: 0000 0001 0010 1100 (300)
*b: 0000 0001           (1)
```

Next, set that byte to 2:

```
 a: 0000 0010 0010 1100 (556)
*b: 0000 0010           (2)
```

Because `*b` is pointing to the second byte of `a`.  Changing it, changes `a` as well.

Comment: It must be noted that the results are not portable due to endianness issues.